Writing an element of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ as a composition of generators
Let $F_n = \langle x_1, ..., x_n | \rangle$ be the free group. Consider the following maps in $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$:

$\sigma_{ij}$ sends $x_i \rightarrow x_i x_j$
$\epsilon_i$ sends $x_i \rightarrow x_i^{-1}$
$g_{ij}$ sends $x_i \rightarrow x_j x_i x_j^{-1}$
$f_{ijk}$ sends $x_i \rightarrow x_i [x_j, x_k]$

Each map fixes all other generators.
How can I write $f_{123}$ as a composition of the $\sigma_{ij}$, $\epsilon_i$, and $g_{ij}$? Ideally in the most straightforward way possible.
The $\sigma_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_i$ generate $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ so this can be done using only those, but I'm interested in the Torelli subgroup of $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ so I included $g_{ij}$. It's a theorem of Magnus that the $g_{ij}$ and $f_{ijk}$ generate the Torelli subgroup.

Well $\sigma_{ij}\sigma_{ik}$ sends $x_i\mapsto x_ix_jx_k$, and similarly $\sigma_{ij}^{-1}\sigma_{ik}^{-1}$ sends $x_i\mapsto x_ix_j^{-1}x_k^{-1}$. So composing these yields the required map
$$ [\sigma_{ij},\sigma_{ik}] : x_i \mapsto x_i[x_j,x_k]. $$
